# How to know initial jumping velocity if I know trajectory as parabola equation and gravity value?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, velocity, projectile

I have a parabola equation $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ with vertex at (vertexX, vertexY)) which draws the object's moving trajectory (from point $A(0;0)$ to $B(X;Y)$). Also, I have a gravity vector ($G(0;-g)$).

How to find the initial velocity which I should to set to this object to move it by this trajectory?

I tried the (vertexY / b, vertexY) but it is too small and doesn't depend on gravity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let initial velocity be $(u_x,u_y)$

differentiating the parabolic equation w.r.t. x gives $\frac{dy}{dx} = b$ when $x=0$

so $$\frac{u_y}{u_x} = b$$

Also from the equations of motion horizontally and vertically using time $t$ to be the time to the vertex $(X,Y)$

$$t=\frac{X}{u_x}$$

$$Y = u_yt -\frac{gt^2}{2}$$

solving these three brings us to a suggestion for your initial velocity of

$$u_x = X(\frac{2}{g}(bX-Y))^{-0.5}$$

and $$u_y = bu_x$$

hope that works...

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Velocity is too small, bots even doesn't stop to touch ground

Comment: @ Robotex could you give an example with $(X,Y)$ and $b$ and the value of $g$ used, let's put the numbers in and see if we are getting the same $u_x$, $u_y$

Comment: Oh, sorry, I made a mistake in formula. Looks like, that is working. Thank you :)

Comment: @ Robotex OK, glad it helped

Comment: @ Qmechanic  the tag edit seems a bit late, the question has been live for 3 hours...

Answer (score 0):

First you have $x(0)=y(0)=0$. $v_y/0)/v_x(0)=b$, second  you have $v_y(vertex)=0, 
 and , v_y(t)=v_y(0)-g*t ,  y(vertex)=v_y(0)*t-g/2*t^2,  x(t)=v_x(0)*t$
this should be enough to find a,b,c

Comment: I have a, b and c. I need to find V0

Answer (score 0):

This formula gives approximately correct result (but with longer time than I put to formula):

Velocity = FVector(
((vertY / Props.JumpTime) + (0.5f * -GravityZ * Props.JumpTime)) / b,
0.0f,
(vertY / Props.JumpTime) + (0.5f * -GravityZ * Props.JumpTime)
);

VertY - the Y of highest point of parabola
GravityZ - gravity magnitude
Props.JumpTime - time for moving